# In batch, how to check if dir names contains a substring while looping?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to loop from current directory to the subdirectories and display only directories that **does not** contain a specific string (**folder1** in this example):

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d %cd%') do ^
set str1=%%G
if not x%str1:folder1=%==x%str1% echo %%G

endlocal
```

But, this script display nothing, yet I do have several subdirectories to go through.

Thank you for your help

Aurel

Comment: Do you notice anything odd in the output if you remove the `@echo off` line and replace the `endlocal` line with `pause`

Comment: Pipe dir output to `find /i /v "folder1` or `findstr /i /v "folder1` to exclude folder1. `for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d ^|find /i /v "folder1" ') Do ...`

Comment: @LotPings: Your method requires to execute _two copies_ of the 400 KB size cmd.exe file in order to execute the two processes at each side of the `|` pipe, and then execute the 16 KB size find.exe or the 30 KB size findstr.exe programs. The same result can be obtained with the simple variable expansion of the original OP's code, so this is not a good advice...

Comment: @Aacini You are right with the two cmd instances, but since the only output are the filtered folder names the whole batch can be replaced with the simple command `dir /b /s /a:d ^|find /i /v "folder1"`  without any for and delayed expansion and I consider THIS a good advice ;-)

Comment: @LotPings: You are right. This is a very good advice as long as the OP not require to do a further processing with the folder names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost done it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d') do (
   set "str1=%%G"
   if not "!str1:folder1=!" == "!str1!" echo %%G
)

endlocal
```

- If you want the `dir` command show folders in current directory, just use `dir /B /S /A:D`; it is not necessary to include the `%cd%` part (in the same way that you type `dir` at the command-prompt, but not `dir %cd%`.
- In `set` command it is convenient to enclose the variable and its value in quotes: `set "str1=%%G"`; this avoids problems caused by any non-visible space. The same apply for the values in `if` command.
- When a variable is modified *inside* a `for` or `if` commands, the *new* value must be expanded via `!` (that is the purpose of `EnableDelayedExpansion`).
- The value of `%%G` replaceable parameter is valid only inside the `for`. Use parentheses to enclose all the commands that goes inside the `for`.